# How to get list of SAP software installed on SLD server using Java

Tags: java, application-server, netweaver

I have SAP SLD system on which some Application servers are installed (ABAPApplicationServer or J2EEApplicationServer) and Application server have some SAP software deployed (SAP HANA 1.0, SAP EM 9.0, etc.) I want to get the details of SAP software deployed on application servers.

There was an [article](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/XI/To+get+software+components%2C+systems%2C+message+server+details+from+system+landscape+directory+in+ABAP#) to get the details of SAP software components in ABAP (EDIT: but not in Java). However, I have not found anything related to the SAP HANA, SAP EM, etc.